# Python requests.get not returning text in one of the tags in html document

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse job descriptions from [Djinni](https://djinni.co/jobs2/) for a personal project. I`m using Python 3.6, BeautifulSoup4 and requests library. When I use requests.get to get html of a job opening page, it returns html without the most critical part - the text of the description. For example, take this page's url - [example](https://djinni.co/jobs2/144172-data-scientist) and following code I wrote:

```
def scrape_job_desc(self, url):
    job_desc_html = self._get_search_page_html(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(job_desc_html, features='html.parser')
    try:
        short_desc = str(soup.find('p', {'class': 'job-teaser svelte-a3rpl2'}).getText())
        full_desc = soup.find('div', {'class': 'job-description-wrapper svelte-a3rpl2'}).find('p').getText()
    except AttributeError:
        short_desc = None
        full_desc = None
    return short_desc, full_desc

def _get_search_page_html(self, url):
    html = requests.get(url=url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 CK={} (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'})
    return html.text
```

It will return the short_desc but not the full_desc. Furthermore, the text of needed <p> tag is not present in the html at all. But when I download the page using my browser its all there. What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full description of the job is stored inside the page in the form of JavaScript variable. You can use `selenium` to extract it, or `re` module:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://djinni.co/jobs2/144172-data-scientist'        
html_data = requests.get(url).text

full_desc = re.search(r'fullDescription:"(.*?)",', html_data).group(1).replace(r'\r\n', '\n')
short_desc =  BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser').select_one('.job-teaser').get_text()

print(short_desc)
print('-' * 80)
print(full_desc)
```

Prints:

```
Together Networks is looking for an experienced Data Scientist to join our Agile team. Together Networks is a worldwide leader in the online dating niche with millions of users across more than 45 countries. Our brands are BeNaughty, CheekyLovers, Flirt, Click&Flirt, Flirt Spielchen.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What you get to deal with:

- Active collaboration with stakeholders throughout the organization;
- User experience modelling;
- Advanced segmentation;
- User behavior analytics;
- Anomaly detection, fraud detection;
- Looking for bottlenecks;
- Churn prediction.
 

You need to have (required):

- Masterâs or PHD in Statistics, Mathematics, Computer Science or another quantitative field;
- 2+ years of experience manipulating data sets and building statistical models;
- Strong knowledge in a wide range of machine learning methods and algorithms for classification, regression, clustering, and others;
- Knowledge and experience in statistical and data mining techniques;
- Experience using statistical computer languages (Python, SLQ, etc.) to manipulate data and draw insights from large data sets.
- Knowledge of a variety of machine learning techniques and their real-world advantages\u002Fdrawbacks;
- Experience visualizing\u002Fpresenting insights for stakeholders;
- Independent, creative thinking, and ability to learn fast.

Would be a great plus:

- Experience dealing with end to end machine learning projects: data exploration, feature engineering\u002Fdefinition, model building, production, maintenance;
- Experience in data visualization with Tableau;
- Experience in dating, game dev, social projects.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic mistake when web scraping.

You probably looked at the source of the rendered HTML in the browser and tried to get the text in the `p` inside the `job-description-wrapper` `div`.

However, if you just load the page itself (the first request handled by your browser) and look at its contents, you'll find that paragraph isn't loaded initially. Some scripting loads the content for it later - but this happens so quickly you hardly notice it as a user.

Check the output from this:

```
print(requests.get(url='https://djinni.co/jobs2/144172-data-scientist').text)
```

That's what's causing the problem. How to solve it is another matter. One way would be to use a headless browser inside your Python that runs the script after loading the page and only when the page completes loading all of it, to grab the content you need. You can look at tools like `selenium` for that.